# Honor URLs moving from magento to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, magento

Not a question about migrating mage site to WP site. Well it is but I am only referring to urls in this question.

I have already created WP site and created a post with the same url as the post was in magento.

In magento it is .com/blog/post/
In WP it is .com/post/

I want the WP site to have the url that magento had so Google and inbound links will auto find new site/pages/posts. At this point the url is different.